# Images are not found on zeromq website

Tags: zeromq

I'am learning zeromq. But some images in the pages of zeromq are not found. I want to get the images since they are very helpful to get the idea of author.

eg:
page: http://www.zeromq.org/whitepapers:brokerless

one of the images missing: http://www.zeromq.org/local--files/whitepapers:brokerless/broker1.png .

The same problem appears in the http://www.250bpm.com/concepts .

I want to submit a bug to the website admin but I got a submit timeout error :(

Is it just a simple network problem? Or anyone else meets the same problem, too? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images work fine from my PC. It might have been a temporary issue with the Wikidot.com service, or it might be an ongoing issue with your firewall (if the images still don't show).

Comment: It's my honor that Pieter answers my question and thanks for your excellent speeches for zeromq :) All images from wikidot.com seem missing on my PC. Maybe there are some problems between my network and wikidot. Is it possible to change the image links to github just as http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all ? It works well. Or any other way that I can get the images?

Comment: Well, I got the images through some other channel, you know. Thanks to Great Firewall to filter all the images from wikidot :(